# Make second column mandatory if the first one has value in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have two columns. The first one is a drop down containing 'yes' and 'no'. The second column becomes mandatory if there is a value in the first column only.
Please guide how do I do that ?

I want to check this validation on `BeforeSave` event.

My code is

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _ Cancel As Boolean) 
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim rngCell2 As Range

    If ActiveSheet.Name="ABC" Then
        Dim lngLstRow As Long 
        lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        
        For Each rngCell In Range("A1:A" & lngLstRow)
            If rngCell.Value <> 0 Then 
                For Each rngCell2 In Range("B1:B" & lngLstRow)
                    If rngCell2.Value = 0 Then 
                        MsgBox ("Please enter a name in cell " & rngCell2.Address) 
                        rngCell2.Select
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next 
    End If
End Sub
```

Its not working.  Going into infinite loop.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't demonstrate any effort for solving the issue. We expect questions to be based on appropriate effort to solve the problem.

Comment: Wait posting my effort

Comment: @MátéJuhász posted my effort

Comment: You test the whole 2nd column against each separate cell in 1st column. You must have one cycle (not 2 nested cycles) from 1 to lngLstRow and build 2 addresses which are tested in pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just go down each row in the used range in column A then see if B is populated or not using Offset.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long

If ActiveSheet.Name = "ABC" Then

    lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For Each rngCell In Range("A1:A" & lngLstRow)

        If rngCell.Value <> "" And rngCell.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
            
            MsgBox ("Please enter a name in cell " & rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Address)
            
            rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            
            Cancel = True
            
            Exit For
            
        End If
    
    Next

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: good answer! Removing empty lines from code would improve readability

Comment: I think that's a matter of choice. I prefer the empty lines.